# Read more... How to replace it with Read less after it's expanded?

Tags: jquery

Could you please help me with this code? I was looking for an asnwer here but its a bit hard for me as I'm a beginner in jquery programming. What I'm trying to do here is to REPLACE the ('read more...') text after it's pressed with ('read less...') for example. I was trying to do it but it fails over and over again. I found other posts here about this, but I would like to use the script I made to train more with this. Any thoughts?
the code is here.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $posts = $('#items > div');
var maxHeight = 95;

$('a', $posts).live('click', function(){
    var $par = $(this).prev('p');

    var oH = parseInt($par.attr('class'));

    if($par.height() == oH){
        $par.animate({
            'height': maxHeight
        }, 'medium');
    }else{
        $par.animate({
            'height': oH
        }, 'medium');
    }
});

$posts.each(function(){
    if($('p', this).height() > maxHeight){

        $('p', this)
            .attr('class', $('p', this).height())
            .css('height', maxHeight+'px');
        $(this).append($('<a>').text('read more...'));
    }
});
```

});

What sort of code and where should I place to replace the 'read more...' with 'read less' after 'read more...' is pressed (it expands - animate down). Apart of replacing the text the script is working fine.. thank you for any help given. I'll kindly appreciate all tips. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the link text by calling `$(this).text('....');`

```
if($par.height() == oH){
    $par.animate({
        'height': maxHeight
    }, 'medium');
    $(this).text('read more...');
}else{
    $par.animate({
        'height': oH
    }, 'medium');
    $(this).text('read less...');
}
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qYtQz/8/)

Comment: The remaining text overflows in the example (Chrome 20 / Mac OS 10.7). Make sure to set `p { overflow: hidden; }` in your CSS.

Comment: I've added it, this is a demo to show how to set the "read more/less" and not to style markup etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will now check it.

Comment: It looks great on your example, however it doesnt display read more and doesnt cut the post on my website, however this is probably my fault i will take a look on it closer. but thank you very much for your help. That's what I was after. It works perfect on the example you sent.

Comment: I like this page - people are so helpful. Great work and thank you for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: WORKING NOW !!! Great work, thank you. I figured what was wrong. Thank you again.